# jQuery clone() isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I seem to have broken the clone function somehow. My jQuery clone function is relatively simple, but doesn't seem to be working. I have two elements, and I'm trying to copy from one to the other:

```
<div id="copy"><span>Some stuff to copy.</span></div>

<div id="paste"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#copy').clone().append('#paste');
});
```

You can see a codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPrBRq

Comment: Two divs with the same id may have a lot to do with it

Comment: Your goal isn't clear but you might want to use appendTo instead of append. Now you're appending (moving) #paste to a clone you don't put in the page, this can't achieve anything useful.

Comment: I was about to say, I think you mean `appendTo`, not `append`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#copy span').clone().appendTo('#paste');
});
```

Fundamentally, `append()` and `appendTo()` perform the same task, however, appendTo is used for appending to a specific element(which is, I believe, what you were going for). Read [more here](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).

Also, your Pen did not have the jQuery library included.

Comment: Duplicating element IDs isn't a great idea

Answer (score 4):

Two problems with that code:

1. You want to use `appendTo`, not `append`. `a.append(b)` appends the content `b` to the element `a`; `a.appendTo(b)` is the other way around, it appends `a` to `b`.
2. You need to remove the `id` of the cloned element; if you don't, you create an invalid document, because `id`s **must** be unique

So:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#copy').clone().removeAttr("id").appendTo('#paste');
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#copy').clone().removeAttr("id").appendTo('#paste');
});
```

```html
<div id="copy"><span>Some stuff to copy.</span></div>
<div id="paste"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should append the cloned element to DOM

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#copy').clone().appendTo('#paste');
});
```